# Delete all sentences containing English in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, language

How can I delete all sentences containing English in Notepad++?

I tried this with words by using find/replace (find `[A-Z] [a-z]` and replacing with blanks), but even with this i stuck with all the remaining blanks and punctuation symbols.

It would also be great if I could not only delete English, but knew how to choose all sentences in a specific language.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do that? What is your use-case, and why do you need Notepad++ for this? What are the other languages involved?

Comment: if you had a script which tagged sentences based on language like <french>......</french>  it could use some algorithm to do that. I doubt NPP would. You could easily delete with notepad++ after that.  You could ask on stackoverflow about the algorithm and programming language. But I don't know why you say about punctuation, if for some reason your A-Z was nearly there, then if you want you could do [-A-Za-z,_.] see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html "Metacharacters Inside Character Classes"

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've worked out the following regular expression;

``` [('``"]?[A-Za-z]+[-!,.'``" ;?)]? ```

This contains three capture sets, the first and last sets of punctuation characters, adjust these as you see fit.

My example text;

```
Dear blah,

Your message is full of blah, but blah no more.  Sorry, I hope Charlie's message gets 
through but as he quotes `don't let the postman talk blah`. The postman often
knocks on the door, and as he does so, he shouts "blah!" - continuing my thought.  
Now for a list(is it really a list?) of blah; blah, blah, blah.

Code; 345345-34545-345435435-34543543
Yours sincerely,


Boris
```

Resulting text;

```
345345-34545-345435435-34543543
```